# Jenkins Pipeline and stash Pull Request Builder not working on PR create/update

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Below is the requirement needed to achieve using the Jenkins Pipeline and i am new bee into Jenkins Pipeline.

- After completing development work and pushing his changes to
  Bitbucket the user creates a pull request.
- In order to approve a pull request we require at least one successful
  Jenkins build. Thereby we would like to get only the build result of
  the code checked in for the pull request.
- When a pull request is created/updated Jenkins shall be triggered
  automatically for real continuous integration.
- The build result shall be reported back to Bitbucket.

**Used Stash Pull Request Builder and stash Notifier for the above process which is working for Normal Freestyle Project.**

We need to migrate the similar functionality using Jenkins pipeline, So have created the jenkins job as below.
[image]
The pipeline script to checks out the PR branch and trigger build is as below

```
node {
    stage('Checkout') {         
        checkout(
        [
            $class: 'GitSCM',
            extensions: [               
                [$class: 'CleanCheckout'],              
            ],
            branches: [
                [name: '']
            ], 
            userRemoteConfigs: 
            [[
                credentialsId: 'id', 
                url: 'repourl.git'
                refspec: ('+refs/pull-requests/*/from:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*/from'), 
                branch: ('origin/pr/${pullRequestId}/from')

            ]]
        ])
    }

    stage('Build') {    
        sh 'make'
    }
    stage('notify') {
      step([$class: 'StashNotifier'])
        try {
        // Do stuff
        currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'     
    } catch(err) {
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILED'
    }
   step([$class: 'StashNotifier'])
 }
}
```

Though i have done the above configuration when i create/update the PR, the build is not automatically triggered in jenkins. I guess the notification from stash to jenkins did not happen because we specify `"origin/${pullRequestId}/from"` in free style project. But i do not have that option to specify in pipeline job.

Tried few alternatives as below.

Instead of stash Pull Request Builder i tried with just "Poll SCM" project and specified cron job to trigger as `"H/2 * * * *`". Upon commits the job is triggered at jenkins. It means that for every commit the jenkins job gets triggered. But **Jenkins should trigger the job when PR is created/updated**.

Also based on below [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513365/jenkins-pipeline-svn-polling),  one answer says "In freestyle job add a trigger to start your pipeline job as build step" which i did not found.

I am missing something here certainly which could be basic and new to jenkins pipeline.

Any hint on achieving the desired behavior?

Comment: edited the question based on findings

Comment: If you are able to add a post receive webhook to your stash/ bitbucket try adding: `Bitbucket Server Webhook to Jenkins` in your Bitbucket repository settings. Then setting `Poll SCM to ""` will stop jenkins from polling, but bitbucket will trigger a build when it has a new commit etc.