# stash pull request builder support for Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pull-request

Does the stash pull request builder plugin support pipeline?
https://plugins.jenkins.io/stash-pullrequest-builder

I tried creating a pipeline job but it fails with Null Pointer exception. I could not find much info on pipeline support however could find this [Jenkins Pipeline and stash Pull Request Builder not working on PR create/update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45038463/jenkins-pipeline-and-stash-pull-request-builder-not-working-on-pr-create-update) but with no answer.

Comment: I don't know if it does or not but I don't use it :) However a bitbucket plugin is what I use and it works nice https://github.com/tomasbjerre/pull-request-notifier-for-bitbucket

Comment: It's working for us. Can you add a code snippet to show us what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like currently there is a bug preventing this, see this issue discussion:
https://github.com/nemccarthy/stash-pullrequest-builder-plugin/issues/142

According to the discussion, a (not yet integrated) fix exists, but I didn't test that. Currently, I use a freestyle job instead (which is able to use the pull request plugin) and simply let it trigger my main pipeline job via a `Build Trigger`.